# When using Curve25519, why does the private key always have a fixed bit at 2^254?

Tags: elliptic-curves, keys, reference-request

When using Curve25519, the private key always seems to have a fixed bit set at position $2^{254}$.

Why is that? Is there any good reason to use a fixed positioned most-significant-bit in the private key?

Comment: You might consider choosing a different answer. I think there are better answers then *"read the paper"*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you take a look at DjB's [paper](http://cr.yp.to/ecdh/curve25519-20060209.pdf)?

One of his design criterias in order to improve performance is *"Use a fixed position for the leading 1 in the secret key"*.

The set of secret keys is defined to be $\{\underline{n} : n \in 2^{254} + 8\{0, 1, 2, 3,\ldots, 2^{251}-1\}\}$.

Comment: That this answer is tautological. I read the paper including those paragraphs and still  Why does having a fixed position for the leading 1 improve performance? I didn't notice an algorithm in the code that relies on this bit being set. Does the code produce incorrect results if this bit is wrong?

Comment: @CodesInChaos I just cited the paper to answer "why it is set to one" as it is listed as a design choice. I did not take a closer look at the arithmetic to find a justification.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I guess the answer is sufficient. The sentence "When using Curve25519, the private key always seems to have a fixed bit set at position 2^254." hints at a question about an implementation. The fact that this is hinted at in a paper is sufficient; why the paper specifies it as such is an interesting but different question.

Comment: The algorithm is intended to be used with mostly floating point operations, the fixed bit is probably there to prevent overflows or something...

Comment: @RichieFrame How would it prevent overflows?

Comment: @forest since a large number like $2^{255}$ needs to be broken into smaller parts, if you know the max value the calculation result of the smaller part will be, you can keep it small enough that there is never an overflow. Example, if your max shift is 9 bits, you can break into 23 bit chunks that never overflow a 32-bit register. Since 253 is divisible by 23, keeping the next bit fixed may allow significantly reduced math with no overflow checks for the final bit. Here, keeping values under $2^{25.5}$ keeps the result inside the full precision bits of a Pentium M floating point register.

Answer (score 55):

[Curve25519](http://cr.yp.to/ecdh.html) was designed to take advantage of the [Montgomery ladder](http://cr.yp.to/bib/1992/montgomery-lucas.ps), which combined with [Montgomery curves](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1987-48-177/S0025-5718-1987-0866113-7/) forgoes the $Y$ coordinates, is side-channel resistant, and enables public keys to be any 255-bit string. The ladder looks something like this (pseudocode):

```
Q[0] = P; 
Q[1] = 2*P;
for(int i = log2(exponent) - 2; i >= 0; --i)
{
  Q[ bit(exponent, i)] = 2*Q[ bit(exponent, i)];
  Q[!bit(exponent, i)] = Q[0] + Q[1];
}
return Q[0];
```

You might notice the format of the loop: the counter is initialized with the index of the most significant bit of the exponent (i.e., the private key), and goes down to 0.

In practice, the first step of the ladder will be to find the most significant bit of the exponent. This is not hard, of course, but doing so may leak, through timing, information about the most significant bits of the exponent: exponents with bit 254 set to 0 will run faster than with that bit set to 1. This can lead to [real problems](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/232).

Curve25519 completely avoids this problem by always setting the most significant bit to 1. This way, the loop always has the same amount of iterations, and no timing information can accidentally be leaked by the variable iteration count.

Comment: Thanks for actually explainingthe underlying reasoning, rather than saying "because djb said so".

Comment: Sorry but I still don't get it. 1) The actual code starts with $P$ and $\infty = (x=1,z=0)$ 2) Why does the code not work if it always starts the ladder at bit 254, but that bit happens to be 0?

Comment: @nightcracker "because djb said so" answers the first point of the question of the OP (it's a design issue). I did not claim that my answer also provides an argument for the second part... ;) Thx to Samuel Neves for providing the answer!

Comment: It is true that the *reference* code protects against this by starting with $(P, \infty)$; however, every textbook displays the version I described, so there's a good chance that an *independent* implementer could make that mistake. Setting that bit to 1 is a preventive measure that costs almost nothing.

Comment: Why doesn't the r-value used in the signature have its bit-254 set? It also runs through `ge_scalarmult_base` in the source code. Further, detectable bias in `r` is more serious than detectable bias in a secret key because every signature uses a unique `r`, so the biases build up. (This is not theoretical, there are lattice-based attacks on ECDSA that do exactly this, which should translate to edDSA without trouble since they only exploit linearity.)

Comment: @AndrewPoelstra You don't want to fix a bit (read: introduce a bias) in the nonce, precisely to avoid [Bleichenbacher-style](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01094002/file/main.pdf) attacks.

Comment: @SamuelNeves Oops, I said almost exactly that, but was thinking of the "detectable bias" resulting from timing analysis of the `ge_scalarmult_base` call during signing. Somehow I did not see that forcing a bit to 1 would be a way more detectable form of bias :)! But then, if implementors are expected to be able to compute rG without revealing their top bit through timing, why assume they can't do the same when computing public keys?

Comment: @AndrewPoelstra It's certainly inconsistent, yes, but also note that the scalar multiplication here is by a fixed base point, unlike in the Diffie-Hellman case. This means that the algorithm used is most likely a comb, which will (likely) not leak the MSB in the same way a Montgomery ladder would. In any case, I suspect this was done in ed25519 more as a backwards-compatibility measure with curve25519 than anything else.