# Order of subgroups formed by Elliptic Curves with a Cofactor

Tags: elliptic-curves, finite-field, group-theory, elliptic-curve-generation

In this question:

[Why are the lower 3 bits of curve25519/ed25519 secret keys cleared during creation?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12425/why-are-the-lower-3-bits-of-curve25519-ed25519-secret-keys-cleared-during-creati/12614#comment168076_12614)

The answer indicates that the order of all points on the curve over the finite field `2^255 - 19` is 8 times the size of the **subgroup** formed by **G**.

i.e. the subgroup size is 
1=`2^252+27742317777372353535851937790883648493` whereas the number of points in the curve **itself** is 8(1).

The answer then states: "*This means that there are a few remaining points that have small order.*"

However, as stated in the answer the `few remaining points` are in fact 8 times the number of points in the cyclic subgroup G.

So how can one conclude that the remaining points form small order groups?

Isn't there scope for a group within the set of **remaining points** to be **bigger** than 1?

How do we know the other points **not** inside 1, **form a variety of small order groups?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The answer indicates that the order of all points on the curve over the finite field $2^{255} - 19$ is 8 times the size of the subgroup formed by $G$.

Obviously, this is incorrect, and Samuel never claims it.

This curve defines a group with $8q$ elements (with $q = 2^{252} + 27742317777372353535851937790883648493$ prime), and the factorization of $8q = 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times q$.  Hence, the possible orders of points are $1, 2, 4, 8, q, 2q, 4q, 8q$.  In addition, this curve happens to be a cycle curve (not all elliptic curve groups are), and so for each possible order, there are in factor at least one group element with that order.

$G$ happens to be one of the points of order $q$ (actually, it didn't just 'happen', a point of that order was deliberately selected to be $G$).

> How do we know the other points **not** inside 1, **form a variety of small order groups?**

Because we know the complete factorization of the number of points on the curve ($8q$).  If there is a subgroup of size $\lambda$, that would imply that $\lambda$ was a factor of $8q$.  We know all the values that are a factor of $8q$, and there are none between 8 and $q$; hence, there cannot be any subgroups with a size between 8 and $q$.

Group theory is your friend.

Comment: > Obviously, this is incorrect, and Samuel never claims it. > I feel like he does claim it, what am I misinterpreting? He literally says:

 "the order of - G is 1=2^252+27742317777372353535851937790883648493 whereas the number of points in the curve itself is 81"

Comment: Otherwise thanks for the answer, it's good. It's not a very intuitive subject so I'm fumbling through it.

Comment: @Woodstock ‘The [total] number of points on the curve is $8p_1$’ does not mean ‘the order of _every_ point on the curve is $8p_1$.’

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage thank you, I thought order meant cardinality here. i.e. p1 is number of points in subgroup, so total number of points isn't 8*2^252...? If not does order here refer to some subgroup number?

Comment: The order of a point $P$ is the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $[n]P$ is the identity.  The order of a _group_ is the number of elements in the group.  The order of a point $P$ is the same as the order of the subgroup generated by $P$.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage thanks so much for the time, that makes sense!

Comment: @poncho thinking about your answer and re-reading it, couldn't there be a subgroup with order 2q? i.e. bigger than q?

Comment: Yes, there is a subgroup of order $2q$ (also $4q$ and $8q$), but they are not interesting because using them brings no security benefit (Pohlig-Hellman) and actually opens some security risks (small subgroup attacks).