# Trying out the small subgroup attack on a group of non-prime order using a simple additive group instead of an Elliptic Curve Group?

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, attack, group-theory

This is the attack I am talking about - [Why are the lower 3 bits of curve25519/ed25519 secret keys cleared during creation?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12425/why-are-the-lower-3-bits-of-curve25519-ed25519-secret-keys-cleared-during-creati/12614#12614)

An elliptic curve group of order $8p$ where $p$ is a prime.

Let $G$ be the generator of the subgroup of order $p$. For ECDH, Alice sends $aG$ to Bob & Bob sends back $h$ instead of $bG$ where $h$ is point on the smaller subgroup of order $8$.

I understand the attack conceptually, I think. I wanted to try it out in a small group of Integers $\pmod {8p}$ instead of a similar elliptic curve group so it's easy to understand.

So I chose $p=11$ & used the group $Z/88Z$. The elements in this group which have order $11$ are these $\{8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 72, 80\}$. All these are multiples of $8$. And the subgroup of order $8$ has these elements - $\{11, 33, 55, 77\}$. All these are multiples of $11$.

So generator $g$ will be a multiple of $8$ & $h$ which is the bad element sent by Bob will be a multiple of $11$. So when Alice calculates $ahg \pmod {88}$, it is always going to be zero. I assume any $ahg$ which is $0$ will not be used by Alice. Isn't that a problem for the attack - that Alice's secret key will always be $0$ & thus the attack will not happen.

So is this attack only valid for elliptic curve groups? I can't think of a reason why. Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or am I doing something wrong?

You're model of what happens within Diffie-Hellman is not correct.

> So generator $g$ will be a multiple of $8$ & $h$ which is the bad element sent by Bob will be a multiple of $11$.

Good so far.

> So when Alice calculates $ahg \pmod{88}$,

That's where you are mistaken; Alice doesn't compute that; instead, she computes $ah \pmod{88}$.  That is one of 0, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, depending on $a \bmod 8$ (assuming Bob selected an $h$ of order 8; if he selected an $h$ of order 1, 2, 4, some of these can't happen).