# Ed25519 to X25519 transportation

Tags: elliptic-curves, ed25519, x25519

Using

```
montgomeryX = (edwardsY + 1)*inverse(1 - edwardsY) mod p
```

it is possible to transport an Edwards curve point (`Ed25519` public key) to the Montgomery curve. Does it have any side effects if the `Ed25519` public key is not valid, in case of a small subgroup or invalid curve attack for example?

And if yes, what would be the best solution to handle that properly?

Comment: Why do you want to convert? Do you want to use the same key for ed25519 and DHKE X25519? They are [birationally eqiuvalent](https://ed25519.cr.yp.to/ed25519-20110926.pdf) are you asking [25519 point validation](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/87709/18298) or [X22519 key exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/68129/18298)?

Comment: My goal is to create a shared secret using x25519 ECDH, but the existing protocol shares ed25519 keys. So to be a bit confusing, both.

Comment: Which protocol are you talking about? X25519 is designed for ECDH. The one who uses Ed25529 for ECDH use it incorrectly. See libsodium..

Comment: not a public protocol, that is a inhouse encryption init step of our connection init. The plan is to create a shared secret using the montgomery curve transported ed25519 public key. Of course ECDH on ed25519 is not the goal.

Comment: Better generate a uniform random key and use a KDF like HKDF have two different keys. It is better than using a single key for both. One is gone all gone!

Comment: And convertion is $$x = \frac{u}{v}\sqrt{-486664}, \quad y = \frac{u - 1}{u + 1}$$ and use XEd25519 as used by Signal uses Curve25519?

Comment: i can see your point. So far i have seen a handful of implementation that does x25519 ECDH using ed25519 key pair, that transvers the edwards curve point to montgomery curve. Is that bad practice?

Comment: Be careful, The signal uses [double rachet for ECHE](https://dspace.cvut.cz/bitstream/handle/10467/76230/F8-DP-2018-Rubin-Jan-thesis.pdf?sequence=-1) so that one can have ephemeral keys.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just create a fresh, ephemeral X25519 keypair for each ECDH, and have each party sign the X25519 public key with their Ed25519 key? That would provide forward secrecy. And if there is a good reason to have long-term keys for ECDH, is there a reason that people can't present both an Ed25519 public key and an X25519 public key to others? They're only 32 bytes each.

Comment: @knaccc yes, that is the way. I saw your comment now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Curve25519 and Ed25519**

A **Montgomery curve** defined over a field $K$ is defined as; $$M_{A,B}: Bv^2 = u^3 + Au^2 + u$$
for certain $A,B \in K$ and with $B(A^2-4) \neq 0$.

**Curve25519** uses prime $q = 2^{255} − 19$ to form the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ and first defined for ECDH and later named [X25519](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/84434/18298). Montgomery equation is $$v^2 = u^3+486662 u^2+u$$ with $486664$ is a square in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, i.e. It is a Quadratic Residue (QR). $u = 9$ has been chosen as a base point with minimal value (a half nothing-in-my-sleeves). The Weierstrass form ( one need for SageMath)

$$y^2 = x^3 + A x + B $$

This curve “Curve25519” is [birationally equivalent](https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/286.pdf) over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ to the Edwards curve **Ed25519** $$x^2 + y^2 = 1 + (121665/121666)x^2y^2$$ with;

$$x = \frac{\sqrt{486664}u}{v}, \quad y = \frac{(u − 1)}{(u + 1)}$$

The reverse operations is;

$$u = \frac{(y + 1)}{(1 - y)}, \quad v = \frac{\sqrt{486664}u}{x}$$

The Edward form has an isomorphic curve

$$-x^2 + y^2 = 1 - (121665/121666)x^2y^2$$ since $-1$ is QR in a $\mathbb Z_p$

---

**Questions**

> `montgomeryX = (edwardsY + 1)*inverse(1 - edwardsY) mod p`
> it is possible to transport an edwards curve point (ed25519 pubic key) to montgomery curve.

Yes, As given above, from Montgomery to Edwards $$u = \frac{(y + 1)}{(1 - y)}$$

> Does it have any side effects if the ed25519 public key is not valid, in case of a small subgroup or invalid curve attack for example?

Edward25519 key can be converted to Curve25519 and if already the secret key is constructed with the [legitimate user's responsibility](https://cr.yp.to/ecdh/curve25519-20060209.pdf)

- The legitimate users are assumed to generate independent uniform random secret keys. A user can, for example, generate 32 uniform random bytes, clear bits 0, 1, 2 of the first byte, clear bit 7 of the last byte, and set bit 6 of the last byte.

In a set definition, we want the secret keys of X25519 as

$$\{n: n \in 2^{254} +8\{0,1,2,\dots,2^{251}-1 \}\},$$ in other words, select a uniform random number between $[0,2^{251}-1]$ multiply it with $8$ than add $2^{254}$.

The order of base point is (little-endian);

```
edd3f55c1a631258d69cf7a2def9de1400000000000000000000000000000010
```

The clearing $0,1,2$ makes sure that

- we are not in a small group for which an attacker takes advantage of DHKE and reveals information at most $\lceil log_2 h\rceil$ bits (the co-factor $h=8$ in Curve25519).
- and clear 7 and [set 6 is against a possible timing attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/11818/18298).

The below is the maximum value (little-endian) and we can see that there two private keys can have the same public key, however, this is a negligible but findable event.

`0x8ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff7`

then there is no need since the birational equivalence will produce points that have no small order if the legitimate user's already used the rules.

*Under the birational equivalence of Curve25519 and edwards25519, each X25519 public key corresponds to two possible Ed25519 public keys)*. X25519 uses only $x$ coordinate (where the name comes) and [Ed25519](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdDSA#Summary) uses the coordinates of the points. When we have only $x$ coordinate of a point, there are two possible points $(x,y)$ and $(x,-y)$ except $y=0$.

> And if yes, what would be the best solution to handle that properly?

There is no danger of [Validating the points](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/87711/18298).

---

**Some extra**

**Using the same key**

I cannot directly say that is insecure, however, our general rule is not to use the same key for different purposes. Until one proves that there is no danger in keeping yourself away from using the same key for different purposes.

It might be better to have one uniform random 256-bit key and derive two keys with HKDF-expand for both X25519 and Ed25519.

**X25519**

Remember that the public key is fixed and when you execute a DHKE this means that you have static-static DHKE. This doesn't have forward secrecy. The better is what Signal protocol does; [Double Ratchet](https://dspace.cvut.cz/bitstream/handle/10467/76230/F8-DP-2018-Rubin-Jan-thesis.pdf?sequence=-1) and you can sign the new public key with Ed25519.

Comment: Can't edit 1 character only, but the spelling in the last linked pdf is "Double Ratchet".

Comment: @PatLee thanks, I corrected.