# Why are hashing private key in Ed22519 key generation and later the modifications required?

Tags: signature, ed25519

In EdDSA with Ed25519 the algorithm of public key computing is following:

```
h = hash (privateKey)
h[0] &= 0xF8
h[31] &= 0x7F
h[31] |= 0x40
publicKey = h * B
```

The questions are

1. Why is Hashing in Ed25519 key generation needed?
2. Why are the actions on h bits are needed?
3. What does the clearing relate to the 31st bit?

Comment: @kelalaka got it, thanks a lot

Comment: Converted those comments into an aswer since the hash part was missing from any answer during my searhes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Hashing in EdDSA key generation

   This is addressed in the [original paper](https://ed25519.cr.yp.to/ed25519-20110926.pdf) as

   > Legitimate users choose $A = [a]B$, where $a$ is a *random secret*; the derivation of a from $H(k)$ ensures adequate randomness.

   If you don't apply the hashing, there is no problem on the verification of the signatures of such public keys.
2. The question is what actions on h bits are needed for?

   This clearly clears the lower bits so that it is a multiple of 8, and this removes the small groups on the curve that this information, although small, can leak in a small-subgroup attack. See more [in this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/12614/18298)
3. The clearing relates to 0th bit and what about 31th?

   This is mainly due to a [possible timing attack (in this site)](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/11811/18298)

Stick to the advises and standards; see [RFC 8709](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc8709.html).